# Golang SQL expected 0 arguments got 1

Tags: go

I am using the following query to query the DB. But I get the error `sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1`.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
row := DB.QueryRow(`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id = "%s";`, userID)
if err != nil {
    return err.Error()
}
```

I am using the following package and driver

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
```

Edit:

I also tried with the following query, but I get the same error.

```
row := DB.QueryRow(`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id = "$1";`, userID)
if err != nil {
    return err.Error()
}
```

Comment: not sure if it is DB-dependent but this article suggests using arguments as numbers prefixed with dollar sign: https://www.calhoun.io/querying-for-a-single-record-using-gos-database-sql-package/

Comment: I tried that, but I get the same error. `\`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id = "$1";\`, userID`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to write a text SQL query in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110601/correct-way-to-write-a-text-sql-query-in-go)

Comment: I tried the approach suggested in that thread but I get same error.

Comment: Please mention the database and the driver used(with versions if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is because you are using a formatted string syntax, but nothing to format it. And the reason why no arguments were expected were probably because the correct placeholders weren't used. Try wrapping up the query in a formatter like `fmt.Sprintf` like:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id = '%s'`, userID)
row := DB.QueryRow(query)
if err != nil {
    return err.Error()
}
```

You can also avoid `fmt.Sprintf`. Instead you can follow a format more specific to the driver you are using. For example

```
// For "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
row := DB.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id=?", userID)

// For "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
row := DB.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id=?", userID)

// For "github.com/lib/pq"
row := DB.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id=$1", userID)
```

Comment: I see. I didn't know that different drivers have different placeholder syntax. Thanks for pointing that out. I will also update the question specifying the driver that I used.

Comment: Another thing is that when I **tried** to use `fmt.Sprintf` to format my query string, `go` threw errors that I was trying to format a `SQL` string. I guess the `mysql` driver doesn't allow to format in that way.

Comment: @VighneshRaut That's not true. You are allowed to use `fmt.Sprintf` in go with the mysql driver. Maybe you have something in your machine to warn you against possible sql injection vulnerabilities? Speaking of which, `fmt.Sprintf` isn't recommended while querying the db as it isn't safe.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351644/golang-slice-in-mysql-query-with-where-in-clause) thread, you basically need to use `?` as a placeholder in the `Query` or `QueryRow` functions. So, the query above should look like this:

```
row := DB.QueryRow(`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id = ? ;`, userID)
if err != nil {
    return err.Error()
}
```