# SQL table name as variable to query

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, pgx

I am using the [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) library to populate a Postgres database in Go.

Following e.g. the tutorial [here](https://www.calhoun.io/inserting-records-into-a-postgresql-database-with-gos-database-sql-package/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110601/correct-way-to-write-a-text-sql-query-in-go), I construct my query like so:

```
// this works
tblinsert = `INSERT into tablename (id, body) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id`
var id string
err := Connector.QueryRow(context.Background(), tblinsert, "value1", "value2").Scan(&id)
```

- Question: I would like to supply the tablename as a variable to the query as well, e.g. change *tblinsert* to `INSERT into $1 (id, body) VALUES ($2, $3)`
- Issue: the above code errors out and returns a "syntax error at or near "$1" (SQLSTATE 42601)" when I run:

  ```
    //this errors out
    err := Connector.QueryRow(context.Background(), tblinsert, "tablename", "value1", "value2").Scan(&id)`.
  ```

I do not fully understand why the error message even references the `$` placeholder - I expected the query to do the string substitution here, just like for the VALUES.

I found similar questions in pure SQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795217/dynamic-sql-table-name-as-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter), so not sure if this is even possible. .

Any pointers on where I am going wrong, or where I can learn more about the `$x` syntax (I got the above to work using `Sprintf`, but this appears discouraged) are much appreciated - I am pretty new to both SQL and Go.

Comment: It's not string substitution, it's a prepared statement, which allows passing SQL values, not query syntax. If you want to do this, you'll need to use string substitution, but I'd urge *extreme* caution in doing so, as this has the potential to create significant security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian makes sense - so there is no way to do this using the `$` sign, I should do a string substitution for the table name, and use `$` for the others? (I understand the injection implications, but this is purely for my own personal use).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. It's a matter of what PostgreSQL supports, and PostgreSQL does not support this. To my knowledge, no database does, but there may be some odd exception.

Comment: The use of `fmt.Sprintf` is usually discouraged to construct SQL queries because of [this](https://xkcd.com/327/), bu you appear to control the set of table names to be used, so I see no problem constructing a string this way. Just make sure you never substitute any user input in a template this way—well, unless you're definitely sure it's properly quoted.